# Uncaught ReferenceError: PrintThisPage is not defined

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP file that calls my print.js to print the page. This file was working on my server perfectly but after I moved the folder to my new server it stopped working. All I did was change the folder name after I moved it but I am confused because there aren't any absolute paths so it should still be working. When clicking the print button, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: PrintThisPage is not defined`. I am not sure what the problem is because everything was working fine before. Can anyone give me some insight why I am receiving this error?

**PHP**

```
<?php render('_header',array('title'=>$title))?>
<div data-role="page" id="XPage" class="bluebg" data-theme="b">
<script language="text/javascript" src="js/print.js"></script>
<script language="text/javascript" src="js/share.js"></script>
<div id="sharecontainer" style="width=100%; text-align: right;">
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" id="print" data-icon="action" data-iconpos="left" data-mini="true" onclick="PrintThisPage()">Print</a>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function PrintThisPage() 
{ 
var sOption="toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,"; 
   sOption+="scrollbars=yes,width=750,height=600,left=100,top=25"; 
var youChoseHTML = $('#youchose').html();
var productHTML = $('#products').html(); 
var warningHTML = $('#warningcontainer').html(); 

var winprint=window.open("","",sOption); 
   winprint.document.open(); 
   winprint.document.write('<html><LINK href=assets/css/printstyle.css  rel=Stylesheet><body onLoad="self.print()">');             winprint.document.write('<img src="assets/img/master.w.m.us.LogoHeader.jpg"><br>');
   winprint.document.write(youChoseHTML);
   winprint.document.write(warningHTML); 
   winprint.document.write(productHTML);
   winprint.document.write('<div class=disclaimer>DISCLAIMER: The information provided is for reference only.</div>');
   winprint.document.write('</body></html>'); 
   winprint.document.close(); 
   winprint.focus(); 
}

function getUrlVars() {
var url = window.location.href,
vars = {};
url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
            key = decodeURIComponent(key);
            value = decodeURIComponent(value);
            vars[key] = value;
            });
return vars;
}
```

Comment: Is `print.js` still located in /js folder?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I never moved anything except change the actual main folder name. I replaced the src as the absolute path and it still gives me the error.

Comment: Right and go to your browser console, click on the `network` tab again reload the page to see if that js file is loaded properly.

Comment: Where in your code the `function PrintThisPage()` is located? in the `print.js` file or somewhere else?

Comment: @EhsanT that is correct, it is in my print.js file

Comment: @SasiVarunan http://i.imgur.com/a13zh5Q.png -- is my print.js supposed to show up in here?

Comment: Yes, it should show up in network tab, Looks like it doesn't even loaded. try `<script src="js/print.js"></script>
<script src="js/share.js"></script>` , for loading [js script](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp) inside html you don't need `script type`

Comment: `language = cdata [CI]
Deprecated. This attribute specifies the scripting language of the contents of this element. Its value is an identifier for the language, but since these identifiers are not standard, this attribute has been deprecated in favor of type.`

Answer (score 0):

So, found the problem. you have:

`<script language="text/javascript" src="js/print.js"></script>`

and you have to change **language** to **type** and it should look like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/print.js"></script>`